# Qt 5.14 QLibrary::resolve() возращает NULL при попытке найти функцию в библиотеке

Tags: c++, qt5

Пишу программу по книге Макса Шлее, я написал программу и библиотеку по листингу но при запуске программа завершает свою работу так как resolve() возвращает NULL из-за того что не находит функцию

Среда MSVC2017 и компилятор тоже от него. Как это можно решить? Я попробовал несколько разных способов из интернета в том числе классический __dllexport но это тоже не работает. Может надо как-то переписать поиск функции в библиотеке?

**dynlib.h**

```
#pragma once

//#include "dynlib_global.h"
#include <QString>
//Листинг 42.2, заключаем экспортируемую функцию в спецификатор
//И таким образом она должна стать доступной при подключении либы
extern "C++"
{
    QString oddUpper(const QString& str);
}
```

**dynlib.cpp**

```
#include "dynlib.h"
#include <QString>

//Листинг 42.3 реализация функции
//Функция преобразует каждый нечетный символ в заглавную букву
QString oddUpper(const QString& str)
{
    QString strTemp;
    for (int i = 0;i < str.length();++i)
    {
        strTemp += (i % 2) ? str.at(i) : str.at(i).toUpper();
    }
    return strTemp;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
//#include "Qt113.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

//Листинг 42.4 
//Проверяем работу функции
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl("this is the example text");
    //Создаем объект который будет загружать и
    //Предоставлять библиотеку для пользования
    QLibrary lib("dynlib");
    //Если столкнулись с ошибкой то выходим
    if (!lib.load())
    {
        qDebug() << "Невозможно открыть файл dynlib.dll";
        return 0;
    }
    //Создаем объявление для функции
    typedef QString(*Fct)(const QString&);
    //Находим и получаем указатель на функци
    Fct fct = (Fct)(lib.resolve("oddUpper"));
    //Проверяем чтобы указатель был получем
    if (fct == NULL)
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Вот здесь прога закрывается
    {
        qDebug() << "Функция oddUpper не найдена";
        return 0;
    }
    lbl.setText(fct(lbl.text()));
    lbl.show();
    //Qt113 w;
    //w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Для начала стоит посмотреть собранный .dll и убедиться, что функция `oddUpper` из него не экспортируется. А потом прочитать про назначение `extern "C++"` и `__dllexport`

Comment: Как раз если делать библиотеку в виде классического проекта не qt то всё хорошо экспортируется, проблемы почему-то только с qt начались. Можно и без него но тогда я лишаюсь всех тех плюшек что даёт qt

Comment: вы читали в документации про `extern "C"`? можете конечно продолжать в c++, но имя вашей функции тогда получается значительно сложнее чем `oddUpper`

Comment: Я только что его применил - extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)QString oddUpper(const QString& str);. У меня функция стала находиться при экспорте но вижла ворчит на это( warning C4190: для "oddUpper" задана С-компоновка, но возвращаемый тип UDT "QString" несовместим с языком Си) несмотря на то что всё работает

Comment: Теперь я попробовал использовать extern "C++" Q_DECL_EXPORT QString oddUpper(const QString& str); при просмотре в hex редакторе самого файла - символьная ссылка там есть и в том числе название этой ссылки, но она по прежнему не обнаруживается методом QLibrary::resolve()

Comment: Я обнаружил что если использовать вместо oddUpper имя прямо из библиотеки "?oddUpper@@YA?AVQString@@AEBV1@@Z" то функция обнаруживается, вызывается и работает исправно. Есть ли какой-то способ сделать попроще? Хотелось бы писать просто oddUpper а не вот такое страшное слово

Comment: Тогда остался вопрос как сделать чтобы вижла не ругалась как в 4 комментарии сверху? Это получается я и классы то не экспортирую без какого-то форменного извращения... Есть же способ наверняка. В книге Шлее как-то скудно написано про dll

Comment: А так ли вам нужна динамическая загрузка? У нее действительно есть ограничения связанные с искажением имен. Автоматическая загрузка может работать с искаженными именами.

Comment: @AlexF не такого требования. Есть только проблема что функции динамической загрузки адресов не знают, какими соглашениями вы пользуетесь в библиотеке и в вызывающей программе, приходится   использовать уловки. При автоматической загрузке динамических библиотек такого нет, сборщик все сделает.

Comment: Примером ручного динамического подключения  сущностей языка С++ в Qt являются плагины. Можно посмотреть как они создаются. При автоматическом подключении .dll все проще

Comment: Если вам нужно грузить либу в рантайме и у вас Qt, возьмите QtPlugins, оно всю эту возню прячет под капот